# How to say pressing something by foot.?

Tags: spoken-english

How do I say pressing something by foot in simple (spoken) English.

eg:

- Press someone else leg by foot
- Press a piece of paper by foot
- Press a banana by foot so that you will slip.

**EDIT**

to make more clear..

above is some situation which I need to speak out. for eg. how to say "if you press banana by foot, your will slip" ? How would I say it correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrase that is usually used in this context is *step on*.

> Step on his foot
>
> I stepped on the piece of paper
>
> Don't step on that banana skin!

Comment: Good. Thanks a lot. Can this phrase be used with children also? Or is there different ways to talk to them?

Comment: Short of not cursing, there is no 'different way to talk to' children in English.

Comment: Stepping on children is frowned upon in most English speaking countries, though...

Comment: @johnrock - When walking with small children, a parent might say, "Be careful where you step," particularly if debris, puddles, or other hazards are nearby.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to 'step on', you could use 'tread on'.

> If you tread on a banana peel, your will slip.
>
> He accidentally trod on her foot.

Comment: thats sounds good.. 'step on' / 'tread on' which one is most commonly used while speaking?

Comment: @johnrock - _Step on_ is [far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=step+on%2C+tread+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) than _tread on_ – particularly in day-to-day conversation.